# I have a problem with an apricot tree

Tags: fruit-trees, apricots

I have a young apricot tree that has fruit on it already here in Albuquerque, New Mexico.  We have some nights coming up that temps will be 32°F (or 0°C - frost).  Do I need to protect the tree if it already has fruit?

Answer (score 1):

Apricots often lose blossoms and fruits to freezes. Some varieties do better in that situation. If you can protect them, that would be advisable.

If this turns out to be a frequent issue, or if your harvest doesn't survive, you might consider getting a nectacot. They're a cross between a nectarine and an apricot, but the one Gurney's sells (Honey Pearls) is supposed to be for zones 4-7 and flower later than apricots. They look pretty similar to apricots. I'm not sure what they taste like.